# Does it make any sense to specify reference type function input parameters as calldata if the given function is only called contract to contract?

Tags: gas, memory, calldata, function

As far as I am aware contract to contract calls store input arguments in memory. Or put more precisely they store them in memory and they can be accessed with CALLDATALOAD within the the new call frame. I am wondering however what is the point of specifying the input argument in a function as calldata, if you know that it will only be called from a contract (hence no gas savings of using the real calldata space which is only used EOA-> Contract calls).

It seems to me that it will be treated as memory either way?

Answer (score 2):

> I am wondering however what is the point of specifying the input argument in a function as calldata, if you know that it will only be called from a contract (hence no gas savings of using the real calldata space which is only used EOA-> Contract calls).

That is not true, calldata is present for both EOA to CA and CA to CA. In the [EVM implementation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/interpreter.go#L112), this is the `input`.

Typically, [executing a transaction](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/2189773093b2fe6d161b6477589f964470ff5bce/core/state_transition.go#L336) [runs the interpreter](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/2189773093b2fe6d161b6477589f964470ff5bce/core/vm/evm.go#L227) the same way the [call opcode](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/2189773093b2fe6d161b6477589f964470ff5bce/core/vm/instructions.go#L690) implementation does.

Doing a `call` , `delegatecall` , `staticcall` from one contract to another will put the data passed along the call in calldata.

You can also see gas consumption gains even if the initial transaction is the same :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract Caller {

    Callee immutable public callee;

    constructor(Callee _callee) {
        callee = _callee;
    }

    function testCallerCalldata(bytes calldata data) external {
        callee.testCalleeCalldata(data);
    }

    function testCallerMemory(bytes calldata data) external {
        callee.testCalleeMemory(data);
    }
}

contract Callee {

    function testCalleeCalldata(bytes calldata data) external {

    }

    function testCalleeMemory(bytes memory data) external {

    }

}
```

Calling `testCallerCalldata` costs less than `testCallerMemory` because the `Callee` contract won't have to copy any calldata to memory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If contract to contract calls function arguments go into calldata and not memory why does one not save on zero bytes within the arguments? Because when EOA calls a contract and the calldata passed along the zero bytes in that calldata cost less then none zero bytes

Comment: also do you see any reason why OZ implementation of ERC721 would specify immutable input params as memory here?

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/49c0e4370d0cc50ea6090709e3835a3091e33ee2/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L70

Comment: For the OZ implementation, I think it's because they are using the `safeTransferFrom` with empty data ( https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/49c0e4370d0cc50ea6090709e3835a3091e33ee2/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L169 ) to be able to reuse the code with data, you cannot do that with calldata location as it would be uninitialized and therefore forbidden.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your first comment though ?

Comment: sry the link seemed to have pointed to the wrong place. I meant the constructor. There doesnt seem to be a reason to specify memory given out discussion above https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/49c0e4370d0cc50ea6090709e3835a3091e33ee2/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L44

Comment: regarding my first comment i meant that when you call a contract from an EOA the input data to the function has different gas costs. For example 0 bytes cost less than none zero bytes. But i think this is because its another way of talking about calldata. As in its a special memory place which is not meant when talking calldata in CA->CA call. In contract to contract calls we talk about calldata that puts the args into memory and make them accessible in the next call frame. If you specify the args as memory, i think the callee as you say has to make another copy of input args to access them.

Comment: Ah no you cannot use calldata in a constructor parameters, you can try it yourself it won't compile.

Comment: right !! thx for the discussion